# How best to propose edits to Ruby documentation?

Tags: ruby

I have a small edit that I would like to propose for existing documentation of Ruby 2.4.0

I found http://documenting-ruby.org/ and https://github.com/documenting-ruby/ruby, but the fork looks no longer maintained.

How should I proceed? Should I submit it as a bug on https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/?

Comment: It's probably best to get in touch with a maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information here:
https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/ruby-core/

I also had a fix for documentation in Ruby and managed to get it it included through the GitHub hosted version: https://github.com/ruby/ruby